# Удаление папки с файлами

Tags: ruby

Подскажите, как я могу удалить папку с файлами через код Ruby. (Использую версию 1.9.2)
Я прочитал что нужно использовать FileUtils но я не знаю, что это, и "с чем его едят?".

Кусок кода:

```
class FileUtils
    Dir.rmdir ("Movies")
end
```

Возникающая ошибка:

[image: Ошибка]

P.S. Мне лень переименовывать файлы нумерацией для того, чтобы сначала удалить их, а потом удалить саму папку.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что даже расширенная поддержка Ruby 1.9.2 закончилась в июле 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Есть замечательный [**модуль** (не класс!) `FileUtils` прямо в стандартной библиотеке](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm_r), где есть целый килограмм часто совершаемых операций над файловой системой. И там есть метод `rm_r`, который рекурсивно (перебирая содержимое вложенных папок) удаляет указанную папку/файл:

```
FileUtils.rm_r('Movies')
```

Comment: В Ruby 2.3 тоже есть такой модуль с таким методом - https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm_r

Comment: @MAXOPKA просто у автора 1.9.2. Замечание в конце ответа не относится к самому ответу, это скорее заметка для автора. И раз уж я это сказал, сделаю-ка я это комментарием...